# Five consequtive SYN-messages from client to server

Tags: tcp, protocol-theory, wireshark

the 5 packages 333 -> 337. What are those and why does the client do this? More generally, why does the client send five SYN-messages to the server?

[image]

Comment: You are ascribing an application-layer concept (client/server) to a layer-4 protocol. TCP doesn't have the client/server concept. TCP it a peer-to-peer protocol, which creates a bi-directional conversation between equals.

Comment: ok, but what program trigger those SYN-calls? it's firing from 5 different ports. Is it to map the ports somehow?

Comment: See my answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see SYN segments originating from five different ports on a host, you could have five different applications on the same host trying to open TCP connections to the same application on another host, or you could have one application trying to open five different TCP connections, or any combination in between.

A TCP connections is uniquely identified by four different things: source IP address, source TCP port number, destination IP address, and destination TCP port number. If all four of those are the same thing, then you have something in a single TCP connection, but if even one is different, it is part of a different TCP connection. When you look at those four data in combination, you see SYN for five different TCP connections.

Why the host is creating five different TCP connections is an application-layer question, which is off-topic here, but one or more applications are trying to open TCP connections. One example is a web browser that can open multiple TCP connections to a web server in order to download different parts of a page at the same time.